# Closed graph theorem between Banach spaces: sufficiency of null sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

For for a linear operator between Banach spaces $T:E \rightarrow F$, why does the seemingly weaker implication $$x_n \rightarrow 0,\quad  Tx_n \rightarrow y \implies y = 0$$
yield
$$x_n \rightarrow x,\quad  Tx_n \rightarrow y \implies y = Tx.$$
I'm new to operator theory and would like to understand the [Closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem#Between_Banach_spaces) better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a consequence of linearity. Suppose you have the formally weaker condition, and you have $x_n \to x$, $Tx_n \to y$. Then put $\xi_n := x_n - x$. It follows that $\xi_n \to 0$, and $T\xi_n = T(x_n - x) = Tx_n - Tx \to \eta := y - Tx$.

By the assumed condition $\eta = 0$, i.e. $y = Tx$. Thus the more general condition follows.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but does this not implicitly assume continuity of $T$? (Which is of course equivalent by the theorem)

Comment: No, it only assumes the additivity of $T$ (not even the full linearity), and it uses the part $Tx_n \to y$ of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the first statement you wrote is true. Now suppose we have $x_n\longrightarrow x$ and $Tx_n\longrightarrow y$. This means $x_n - x \longrightarrow 0$ and $Tx_n - Tx = T(x_n - x)\longrightarrow y - Tx$ (due to linearity of $T$) and it follows that $y - Tx = 0$ or $y = Tx$.